# Como cancelar a execução de uma função em C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, email, runtime

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação desktop em C# WPF na qual existe uma função responsável pelo envio de email `EnviarEmail()`, quando essa função é executada ela demora um certo período de tempo para que seja executada por completo.
E quando ela está sendo executa todo o form é travado, ou seja, não é possível fazer nada.

Como é possível fazer um botão "Cancelar" que ao ser clicado ele cancele a execução da função `EnviarEmail()` e que quando ela for executada ele não fique bloqueado "O botão cancelar"?

```
ClickButtonEnviarEmail(){
    EnviarEmail();
}

private void EnviarEmail(){
   .
   . // Enviando Email ~ isso pode demorar um certo tempo, 

 e caso o usuario queira cancelar o envio do email, como é possível
 fazer?
        .
     }
```

Como é possível solucionar esse problema?

Comment: Estou achando um pouco ampla, precisaria ver como está fazendo. Mas basicamente tem que criar um evento no botão que dispare um método que faça o cancelamento. Obviamente que não poderia ter um método "linguição" que faça o envio, ou até poderia mas aí em cada passada no laçao teria que verificar se o botão foi acionado, que provavelmente *setaria* uma *flag*.

Comment: Mas por exemplo, e se for apenas o envio de 1 email? smtp.Send(mail) para enviar o email de fato por demorar um certo tempo, e se eu quiser cancelar esse envio?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

É possível fazer isto conforme mostra a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasynccancel?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Net_Mail_SmtpClient_SendAsyncCancel). Fora isto tria que pegar uma biblioteca mais completa. O exemplo constante lá:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace Examples.SmptExamples.Async {
    public class SimpleAsynchronousExample {
        static bool mailSent = false;
        private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
            // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
             String token = (string) e.UserState;
            if (e.Cancelled) {
                 Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Send canceled.", token);
            }
            if (e.Error != null) {
                 Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", token, e.Error.ToString());
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
            }
            mailSent = true;
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Command line argument must the the SMTP host.
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(args[0]);
            // Specify the e-mail sender.
            // Create a mailing address that includes a UTF8 character
            // in the display name.
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("jane@contoso.com", 
               "Jane " + (char)0xD8+ " Clayton", 
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            // Set destinations for the e-mail message.
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com");
            // Specify the message content.
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            message.Body = "This is a test e-mail message sent by an application. ";
            // Include some non-ASCII characters in body and subject.
            string someArrows = new string(new char[] {'\u2190', '\u2191', '\u2192', '\u2193'});
            message.Body += Environment.NewLine + someArrows;
            message.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            message.Subject = "test message 1" + someArrows;
            message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            // Set the method that is called back when the send operation ends.
            client.SendCompleted += new 
            SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
            // The userState can be any object that allows your callback 
            // method to identify this send operation.
            // For this example, the userToken is a string constant.
            string userState = "test message1";
            client.SendAsync(message, userState);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending message... press c to cancel mail. Press any other key to exit.");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            // If the user canceled the send, and mail hasn't been sent yet,
            // then cancel the pending operation.
            if (answer.StartsWith("c") && mailSent == false) {
                client.SendAsyncCancel();
            }
            // Clean up.
            message.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/Cancelling.cs).

Comment: No caso meu button Cancelar teria como evento no click o SendCompletedCallback ?

Comment: Não sei, como eu comentei, a pergunta não fala nada como está o seu código. Mas eu diria que não, seria algo para chamar `client.SendAsyncCancel();`. Note que eu nem sei se resolve o que deseja, é uma forma, mas pode ser que você precise de algo que permita interação.

Comment: certo consegui entender o código, mas o problema é que quando eu entro na função para enviar o email a tela fica bloqeuada até que a função seja completada, como faço para que isso não aconteça?

Comment: Aí já começa ter dúvida em cima de dúvida. Eu nem devia ter respondido. Você precisa ter um problemas mais específico, mas bem definido. Você lançou uma dúvida geral, eu dei uma resposta geral.